# Is is possible to use a PTBNL to cover certain contingencies?

Tags: mlb

Then one I'm thinking of is Giancarlo Stanton, who will have the ability to "opt out"from (or "opt in") to his contract after 2020.

Would it be possible (within the rules) for Miami to trade Stanton to another team for X, which is all the Marlins get if he opts out, but the receiving team surrenders a PTBNL (player to be named later) if Stanton opts in after 2020, and plays out the rest of his contract? That would probably come from the receiving team's then farm system, with some restrictions.

(My recollection was that e.g. Trea Turner was a PTBNL in a trade, because it was against the rules to trade him within 12 months of drafting/signing him.)